# REST service and race conditions

Tags: java, rest, race-condition

Let's imagine a problem:
I have a REST service, which is implemented using Java/MySQL/Spring and HTTP/JSON technologies.
The clients of the REST service are mobile applications. 
So it's possible that someone will decompile the code and will get the API of the REST service.
( Yes, the code is obfuscated etc, but anyway ).

Problem: there is a POST method to send money to other user of the application.
I am worried, that someone can get the API, write a bot and make this POST request 500 or 5,000 or even 50,000 times per second.
As a result, he might send more money than he actually has, because if 1000 requests are processed simultaneously then the balance checking might be
successful for all 1000 request, however the real amount of money on an account might be enough only for, lets say, 50 requests.

So, basically, it's more like the standard "race" condition with multiple threads.
The problem is, that I have multiple servers and they are not related with each other anyhow.
So, 300 request can come to server A, 300 requests can come to server B and rest requests can come to server C.

The best idea what I have is to use something like "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" and synchronize on database level.
However, I would like to consider another solutions.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Don't you have logins, sessions, and anti-csrf tokens to ensure that transfer requests can only come from a logged in, authorized user? Don't you have authorization checks to ensure that only requests to transfer one's own money are respected? Don't you have a three tier application so the front end is only handling the presentation layer and the business logic is handled behind the scenes? Don't you have the ability to segment processing for like requests (same donator, same target, etc) all within a single business logic server?

Comment: How logins/sessions can prevent this? If someone hacks the API, he can hack the login/session and send this request using valid authentication mechanism. By the way, authentication is token-based, ie OAuth. It's a REST-service and I don't use csrf tokens.

Comment: If you have people log in, and restrict things so that people can only spend their own money, then you prevent attacks where an attacker would spend someone else's money. It doesn't prevent them from overdrawing their own account, but it does prevent them from overdrawing *someone else's* account.

Comment: You might also want to look into overdraw fees, just like banks do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Rely on ACID implementation of the database (MySQL in your case). Assuming you  are using InnoDB engine, you need to choose the right transaction isolation level ([SET TRANSACTION syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html)) in combination with the right locking reads mechanism ([SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE Locking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)). You need to understand these concepts well in order to do the right choice. It might be possible that simply using the right isolation level will already prevent the race condition even without the locking reads. The cons are you are trading off consistency for scalability and tying your application to RDBMS database thus it will be more difficult for you to move to NoSQL for example.
2. Decompose your back end into web tier and service tier (option suggested by atk in the comments). This will allow you to scale the web tier instances independently while keeping a single service tier instance. Having a single service tier instance makes it possible to use Java synchronization mechanisms such as `synchronised` blocks or `ReadWriteLock`. Although this solution will work I wouldn't recommend it since it reduces the scalability of your service tier.
3. This is an enhancement of the previous option. You can use a [Distributed lock manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager) instead of built-in java synchronization mechanisms. It will allow you to scale your web tier and service tier independently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Distributed lock manager might be a bad idea for scalability.

I will try to play with RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

For mission critical applications, it's best to have multiple levels of locking mechanisms.

"SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" is a good way to do so, but they're pretty expensive, and when you try to bombard this with Charles, you'll see that your upper API stack will suffer, and that simple mechanism will cripple your infrastructure pretty easily, much like a DDoS event.

Implement it at the Load Balancer/Proxy layer first, to throttle N-number of requests per specified intervals from a single IP address.

Then apply a shared cache layer lock, where all your boxes go to synchronize on certain keys depending on which critical transaction you want to lockdown.  For example, you can use Redis GETSET or INCR functionality to atomically set a flag, before entering the critical code path.  Reject anything else quickly to avoid those bad actors from holding on to CPU/memory.

You can also implement things like an APC cache (before hitting your Redis / Memcache cluster) to do similar locking on a per box basis.  This is quicker as there's no network latency involved.

The above are necessary on top of using "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE"